# What does the Request object do in the following scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I see something like:

```
if(Request["Email"])
{

}
```

What does this actually mean?  Where is the Email collection member actually being set?

Comment: How can this not be a real question to the one who voted to close it so far.

Comment: No, the code is just if(Request["Email"]).  Maybe Request["Email"] is short for Request.Form, I am not sure.  I understand sort of what Request does, but I am unclear on where Email comes from.  Is this something set by the programmer, if so where?

Comment: @Brandon  The Item property of the Request object is an indexer property.

Comment: @Darthg8r, right you are. I'm just use to always looking specifically at the QueryString or Form collections. :P

Comment: So is Request["Email"] just a short form of Request.Item["Email"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's retrieving the variable from get/post parameters.

somepage.aspx?blah=1

> string blahValue = Request["blah"];
>
> Console.WriteLine(blahValue);

> 1

Even more specificially:

Cookies,  Form,  QueryString or  ServerVariables

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_members(VS.71).aspx

Comment: ah ok, so Email is being set in the url or possibly through get, so I would not see it in the query string, correct?

Comment: + dont forget to check if the index exists. Dont know if ASP will give error on missing hash index but if it does it will not be fun.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, it will just return null. You could always do Request["blah"] ?? "" just to make sure a string is returned if your really wanting one

Comment: Funny thing is, I don't see it in a query string or in any form values unless it is hidden somewhere.

Comment: Are you using MasterPages? It could be the actual value of Request["Email"] comes from some input field (hidden or otherwise) on the masterpage. Or it could be the page is called from a different page (using that Page's PostBackUrl) that does have an email field on it...

Comment: I will investigate.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948.aspx) for example.

**Taken from the above link**

All variables can be accessed directly by calling  Request(variable) without the collection name. In this case, the Web server searches the collections in the following order:

- QueryString
- Form
- Cookies
- ClientCertificate
- ServerVariables

Answer (score 1):

It retrieves either the submited form values (POST) or the submitted querystring values (GET).

You would generally see it written as either Request.Form["Email"] or Request.Querystring[Email"] instead of just Request["Email"].

Example of Form (POST) method:

On the HTML or ASPX Page:

```
<form action="SomePage.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="Email" value="someaddress@email.com" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Once the form has been submitted by clicking the Submit Form button you would retrieve the form values using Request.Form["Email"] (or just Request["Email"] for the lazy :))

Answer (score 0):

Just some additions to the posts of the others.

To have things more explicitly you normally use `Request.QueryString[...]` for getting values from the QueryString, so when a GET request has been done and `Request.Form[...]` when a POST request is done. Although in the latter case you usually directly access the values of your server controls, since ASP.net uses the ViewState mechanism to load back on your controls when the request comes back from the client.